# Does Fabric8io K8s java client support patch() or rollingupdate() using YAML snippets?

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I am trying to program the patching/rolling upgrade of k8s apps by taking deployment snippets as input. I use `patch()` method to apply the snippet onto an existing deployment as part of rollingupdate using [fabric8io's k8s client APIS](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client).. Fabric8.io `kubernetes-client` version `4.10.1`
I'm also using some loadYaml helper methods from `kubernetes-api 3.0.12.`

Here is my sample snippet - adminpatch.yaml file:

```
    kind: Deployment   
    spec:
      strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 1
          maxUnavailable: 0     
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: ${PATCH_IMAGE_NAME}
              image: ${PATCH_IMAGE_URL}
              imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I'm sending the above file content (with all the placeholders replaced) to patchDeployment() method as string. 
Here is my call to fabric8 patch() method:

```
     public static String patchDeployment(String deploymentName, String namespace, String deploymentYaml) {
    try {
    Deployment deploymentSnippet = (Deployment) getK8sObject(deploymentYaml);
    if(deploymentSnippet instanceof Deployment) {
            logger.debug("Valid deployment object.");
    Deployment deployment = getK8sClient().apps().deployments().inNamespace(namespace).withName(deploymentName)
        .rolling().patch(deploymentSnippet);
    System.out.println(deployment.toString());
    return getLastConfig(deployment.getMetadata(), deployment);
    }
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
      Ex.printStackTrace();
    }
      return "Failed";
  }
```

It throws the below exception:

```
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure
> executing: PATCH at:
> https://10.44.4.126:6443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/patch-demo.
> Message: Deployment.apps "patch-demo" is invalid: spec.selector:
> Invalid value:
> v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"nginx",
> "deployment":"3470574ffdbd6e88d426a77dd951ed45"},
> MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is
> immutable. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=422,
> details=StatusDetails(causes=[StatusCause(field=spec.selector,
> message=Invalid value:
> v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"nginx",
> "deployment":"3470574ffdbd6e88d426a77dd951ed45"},
> MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is
> immutable, reason=FieldValueInvalid, additionalProperties={})],
> group=apps, kind=Deployment, name=patch-demo, retryAfterSeconds=null,
> uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status,
> message=Deployment.apps "patch-demo" is invalid: spec.selector:
> Invalid value:
> v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"nginx",
> "deployment":"3470574ffdbd6e88d426a77dd951ed45"},
> MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is
> immutable, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null,
> resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}),
> reason=Invalid, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

I also tried the original snippet(with labels and selectors) with `kubectl patch deployment <DEPLOYMENT_NAME>  -n <MY_NAMESPACE> --patch "$(cat adminpatch.yaml)` and this applies the same snippet fine.

I could not get much documentation on fabric8io k8s client patch() java API. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember we do support patching with full resource object. We don't support patching with raw json, but I think it should work the way you're doing it. Are you sure you have correct `Deployment` being received from `getK8sObjectFromYamlConfig()` ?

Comment: Thanks @RohanKumar . In the response that I get, I printed it out and it has not updated the image. Also the pod description after patch shows the old image. Does the typecasting look OK? `Deployment deploymentSnippet = (Deployment) getK8sObjectUsingYamlConfig(deploymentYaml);`

Comment: @RohanKumar 


I also check `if(deploymentSnippet instanceof Deployment)` before it calls k8s patch call. and it does not complain. Updated original post with the latest code I have.

Comment: I am using fabric8 version 4.3.1.  A little old.. may be this is implemented recently?  I will try with latest version

Comment: Is this project hosted somewhere so that I can try to reproduce this ? Maybe a simple reproducer of patching something into a Depoyment?

Comment: Hi @RohanKumar, no, unfortunately this is behind firewall and we have a lot of helper methods to read the yaml file and convert it to `Deployment` type. I am assuming all these worker methods are OK because `instanceof Deployment` passes . Can you please point me to an example usage or documentation on this patch() API?  Am I missing someh=thing n my patch snippet that is mandatory probably?

Comment: More info: To load yaml file and get a Deployment object back, we are using loadYaml helper methods from kubernetes-api 3.0.12 jar.  Is there a github link to this project? Is this an active project and the APIs from 3.0.12 version is compatible with kubernetes-client 4.10.1?

Comment: Hi @RohanKumar,  I re-read your 1st comment - "As far as I remember we do support patching with full resource object." . What does "full resource object" mean? My original deployment has two containers in it. I am trying to patch only one of them. Would that qualify as a full resource object? Or should I mention the other image name and url too?

Comment: This was my mistake that the Deployment object being returned was the one that is up and running and not the one from the yaml snippet.I resolved it and now I am down to the real issue. Updating the original post.

Comment: oh, cool. I'm glad that it finally worked out for you :-) . I was really busy yesterday so couldn't find time to look into your issue.

Comment: Thanks @RohanKumar . Do you have any recommendation on what libraries I can use to convert my patch YAML  to a valid K8s object ? The loadYaml APIs I have (taken from kubernetes-api jar) seem to return null when it gets a patch YAML.

Comment: Umm, `kubernetes-api` jar has been marked as deprecated. Are you using it for some other operation also? I think we should port this loadYaml class into fabric8 Kubernetes client Serialization package and fix it there

Comment: @RohanKumar I see. I couldn't find a `deprecated` tag on this link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric8/kubernetes-api       we use some util methods from kubernetesHelper.. Is there an alternative library you would recommend to convert patch yamls into k8s objects?

Comment: If I add `kind: Deployment` to my patch yaml, the `loadYaml()` method works but then `patch()` method fails saying the selectors doesn't match the labels. But initially when I had all the labels and selectors, the `patch()` fails saying these fields are immutable.  What are the mandatory fields in a patch yaml for `patch()` method to work. Some documentation would be helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With latest improvements in Fabric8 Kubernetes Client, you can do it both via `patch()` and `rolling()` API apart from using `createOrReplace()` which is mentioned in older answer.

### Patching JSON/Yaml String using `patch()` call:

As per latest release v5.4.0, Fabric8 Kubernetes Client does support patch via raw string. It can be either YAML or JSON, see [PatchTest.java](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/PatchTest.java#L107). Here is an example using raw JSON string to update image of a Deployment:

```java
try (KubernetesClient kubernetesClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
  kubernetesClient.apps().deployments()
    .inNamespace(deployment.getMetadata().getNamespace())
    .withName(deployment.getMetadata().getName())
    .patch("{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"name\":\"patch-demo-ctr-2\",\"image\":\"redis\"}]}}}}");
}
```

### Rolling Update to change container image:

However, if you just want to do rolling update; You might want to use `rolling()` API instead. Here is how it would look like for updating image of an existing Deployment:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    // ... Create Deployment 

    // Update Deployment for a single container Deployment
    client.apps().deployments()
            .inNamespace(namespace)
            .withName(deployment.getMetadata().getName())
            .rolling()
            .updateImage("gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0");
}
```

### Rolling Update to change multiple images in multi-container Deployment:

If you want to update Deployment with multiple containers. You would need to use `updateImage(Map<String, String>)` method instead. Here is an example of it's usage:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    Map<String, String> containerToImageMap = new HashMap<>();
    containerToImageMap.put("nginx", "stable-perl");
    containerToImageMap.put("hello", "hello-world:linux");
    client.apps().deployments()
            .inNamespace(namespace)
            .withName("multi-container-deploy")
            .rolling()
            .updateImage(containerToImageMap);
}
```

### Rolling Update Restart an existing Deployment

If you need to restart your existing Deployment you can just use the `rolling().restart()` DSL method like this:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    client.apps().deployments()
            .inNamespace(namespace)
            .withName(deployment.getMetadata().getName())
            .rolling()
            .restart();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the related bug in Fabric8io rolling API: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/1868

As of now, one way I found to achieve patching with fabri8io APIs is to :

1. Get the running deployment object
2. add/replace containers in it with new containers
3. use the `createOrReplace()` API to redeploy the deployment object

But your patch understandably could be more than just an update to the containers field. In that case, processing each editable field becomes messy.

I went ahead with using the official K8s client's patchNamespacedDeployment() API to implement patching. https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/356109457499862a581a951a710cd808d0b9c622/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/PatchExample.java